# Set DNS timeout for WCF webservice

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0

I am using Visual Studio 2012 to generate a web service to be used by a winforms client.  I created the client side by using "add service reference".  This winforms client is a .net c# replacement of an old VB 6 app.  Previously, in the VB app there were external settings for timeout values including the following:

DNS timeout
Connect timeout
Request timeout

The DNS timeout would work when the endpoint host address is a FQDN forcing a DNS lookup.  The timeout value here would place a limit on the amount of time to wait for DNS resolution.

The connect timeout would place a limit on the amount of time the winforms client would wait to establish an http connection to the server.  DNS lookup would have been successful.

The request timeout would place a limit on the amount of time to wait for the request to return after an http connection was successful.  This would come into play if a long running query took too long after the web service call was initiated.

Is there something similar to the above in .net 4.0.  I would like to be able to configure this in the app.config.  I do know about the below.

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="IncreasedTimeout" 
      openTimeout="12:00:00" 
      receiveTimeout="12:00:00" closeTimeout="12:00:00"
      sendTimeout="12:00:00">
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
```

Could these map to the ones I need or does it really not matter?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OpenTimeout` setting for the WCF binding is for the length of time to wait when opening the channel, so I believe this will be analogous to your old Connect timeout. This should be fast so you normally would only want to specify a few seconds to wait (30 or less), not 12 hours.

The WCF `CloseTimeout` is for when a Close Channel message is sent, and this is how long to wait for an acknowledgement. This may not have an equivalent in your old architecture. Again, this should be fast and should only need a few seconds.

The WCF `SendTimeout` (for the client config) essentially covers the time for the Client to send the message to the service, and to receive back the response (if any). This would correspond to your old Request timeout. This may need to be for several minutes if your server takes a while to process things.

The WCF `SendTimeout` (for the server config) is for when you want callbacks, so that the Server knows how long to wait for acknowledgement that its callback was received.

The WCF `ReceiveTimeout` does not apply to client-side configuration. For Server-side config the ReceiveTimeout is used by ServiceFramework layer to initialize the session-idle timeout (to be honest I don't really know what that is)

This MSDN discussion may be helpful http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/84551e45-19a2-4d0d-bcc0-516a4041943d/explaination-of-different-timeout-types?forum=wcf

As a final note, having really big timeout values isn't a good idea unless you definitely have long running requests. This is because you can run out of available resources on your server if the client isn't closing the connections properly.

Comment: Looks like DNS timeout would be part of OpenTime.  I think this will be fine.  I can't control DNS lookups anyway since I don't have control over those servers.

Comment: SendTimeout is the main one and I was able to set it very low and trigger timeout exception.  OpenTime I set very low as well but never triggered a timeout exception.

Comment: That's been my experience too. I'm using 30 seconds for OpenTimeout, but I probably should be using 5 or 10 since the literature I've read says that in a closed environment like mine the opening and closing of channels should be more like a second or less. But I'd always rather give myself a bit of buffer.